# Python Keras - How to save only the best model without losing information about loss, acc, val_loss and val_acc metrics?

Tags: python, keras, callback, metrics, model-checking

Up to now, I have saved models in this way:

`checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('Model-{epoch:05d}-{loss:.4f}-{acc:.4f}-{val_loss:.4f}-{val_acc:.4f}.h5', verbose=0, monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')`

However, this creates a lot of files on the disk that I then have to delete, leaving only the best models. How do I get the loss, acc, val_loss and val_acc information from the best model (the last one saved using ModelCheckpoint) without storing them in the file name?

I tried to get the data from history.history, but all the values are stored there and I don't know which is the best. I can also easily get these parameters from the model from the last epoch. What I can't do is access the parameters of the best model.

Comment: What's preventing you from overwriting the same file each time training yields a good model?

Comment: I can overwrite a file with the same name, i.e. not containing the model metrics in the name. And I need these metrics.

Comment: What if you write the metrics to a `txt` file? You would need a custom callback for that, executed at the end of every epoch or when the best model gets written to disk.

Comment: Such a solution would be perfectly fine, but I'm afraid I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @stateMachine can I ask for tips on how to do this?